# Pourquoi cette proposition subordonnée est-elle un attribut ?

Tags: grammaire, attributs

De ["Adjectif attribut du sujet" (francaisfacile.com)](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-29829.php):

> `10.` L'important est **(que chacun s'entende bien)** au sein de ce groupe.

Puisque **(que chacun s'entende bien)**  n'est ni adjectif, nom, infinitif, proposition, ou pronom (au vu des critères plus haut dans la page), j'imaginais que c'était un COD, mais j'avais tort.

Pourquoi cette proposition relative est-elle un attribut ?

Comment: Ce n'est pas une proposition subordonnée relative, mais une proposition subordonnée conjonctive.

Answer (score 2):

C'est la nature du verbe qui définit la distinction attribut/complément (J'en parle brièvement dans [ma réponse à ton autre question](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/9101/926))

Grosso modo, l'*attribut* est une notion qui correspond au *[predicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression)* anglais. La distinction vient de ce qu'il ne s'agit pas de quelque chose impliqué dans une action (ce qui est généralement le cas dans les verbes transitifs) faite par le sujet, mais plutôt de quelque chose qui *décrit* le sujet. *Être* est le verbe le plus commun qui s'accompagne d'un attribut.

Cette distinction est nécessaire car les verbes attributifs et les verbes transitifs n'admettent pas les même constructions syntactiques: un verbe attributif, par exemple, ne peut pas se mettre à la voie passive, contrairement à un verbe transitif.